# PHP Undefined Arrays returning wrong values

Tags: php, arrays

This might seem weird to ask such a stupid question. 
However, I am not able to figure out why I am getting wrong value with such a small piece of code.

Code is:

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);
$result_all = 'User not found';
if($result_all['BookingDetail']['BookingReference']){
     echo "<br>Output in if :- ".$result_all['BookingDetail']['BookingReference'];
}else{
     echo "<br>Output in else:- ".$result_all['BookingDetail']['BookingReference'];
}
```

[image]

I expected output to be blank however it returns first character of the string. I know checking if its `is_array` and `isset` will resolve my problem.

But I want to understand why its happening?

Comment: there is confusion in your code, you have assigned $result_all as a variable and on another line you are checking it for array ?? how it is possible ?

Comment: This variable is string not an array `$result_all `, you are overriding this variable to string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem:-

> You are assigning `'User not found'` to `$result_all` variable in your script, which makes it a string variable.
>
> Since `$result_all` is a string, any index like `BookingDetail` is considered as 0 for the string and that's why it will give the first character of string

Solution:-

You need to use `isset()` to check index exist or not?

```
<?php
//comment these two lines when code started working fine
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

if( isset( $result_all['BookingDetail']['BookingReference'] ) ){
    echo "<br>Output in if :- ".$result_all['BookingDetail']['BookingReference'];
}else{
    echo "<br>Output in else:- User not found";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran this on PHP 7.3

This is the output:

```
Output in if :- UIllegal string offset 'BookingReference' on line 5
```

Please consider upgrading your PHP version

Answer (score 0):

Because you convert it in array because of the same name of the variable.

> `$result_all` in ARRAY by doing this `$result_all['BookingDetail']['BookingReference']`

and not define which value of array you want to show so by default it showing the first character of string.

> `$result_all = 'User not found';`
>   Output:- U